# Apollo refetching when using with React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

We're developing our complete first app with Apollo and we are having an issue when using it with react-router.

We are using the new  component and the problem is when we change the route of the app it uses the data originally was fetched (even if the data changed on the server):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

import { GET_FAVORITE_JOBS } from './graphql';
import FavoriteJobList from './stateless';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Query query={GET_FAVORITE_JOBS}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => (
        <FavoriteJobList loading={loading} error={error} data={data} />
      )}
    </Query>
  </div>
);
```

I've seen this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#refetching

Do we have to use `refetch` on `componentDidMount`?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So You have 2 possibilities:

> 1, Define some random input to your query, and pass it in. like this:

```
export default () => (
  <div>
    <Query query={GET_FAVORITE_JOBS} variables={{ random: New Date().getTime() }}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => (
        <FavoriteJobList loading={loading} error={error} data={data} />
      )}
    </Query>
  </div>
);
```

> 2, Export as a container and acces the result as a props:

```
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";

const SomeComp = (props) => (
  <div>
    // You can acces the results here as props. 
    // Also You can use props.refetch() as an action or component lifecycles
  </div>
);
export default graphql(GET_FAVORITE_JOBS, {
  name: "getFavJobs",
  options: (props)=> ({
    variables: {
      random: New Date().getTime()
    }
  })
})(SomeComp));
```